# How do I find all matches of a template in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use `matchTemplate` function to find company's logo in source image.so i referred [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html).

But my problem is:

The source image may contain many almost the same logos which is matched the template, and some other company's logo (unmatched).

How to find all matches not only the best match, just like detectMultiScale which gives output in a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the template matching in a while loop where as a condition you ask if a match was found or not (with some certainty threshold). At the end of every loop save the match and mask out the area, so that it will not be found again. When the certainty drops under the level, break out from the loop.

Pseudo code:

```
while true:
    maxLoc, maxVal = template_matching()  # perform the matching
    if(maxVal < threshold)  # check if it is a good match and break if not
        break
    list.append(maxLoc)  # save the location of a good match
    mask_out(src, (maxLoc.x + template.cols , maxLoc.y + template.rows)) # mask out the area, so that it's not found again

draw_all_rectangles(list)
```

Remember that depending on template matching method used, you will either use minVal and minLoc or maxVal and maxLoc. With minVal the condition will use the opposite inequality symbol. I'll leave the implementation to you. Good luck.